# Select pairs of values and assign variables names in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, row

Ok, I have been trying to do this for some time now, but no success.

I need to select many pairs of values from my database and assign them different variables names to work later on my code and to display to the user when he logs in.

Let's say that this is my "history_pruchases" table:

```
ID     BUYER_NAME    PURCHASE_DATE
1      John        2013-01-01 10:00:00
2      Pete        2013-01-02 10:00:00
3      Jenn        2013-01-03 10:00:00
4      Mark        2013-01-04 10:00:00
5      Zuck        2013-01-05 10:00:00
6      Berg        2013-01-06 10:00:00
7      Berg        2013-01-07 10:00:00
8      Pete        2013-01-08 10:00:00
etc
```

My problem is that I need to do some dynamic assignment here.

Based on "BUYER_NAME" and "PURCHASE_DATE" I will make another query later.
So I need a var that I can manipulate and split if needed.

```
$VAR = BUYER_NAME.PURCHASE_DATE
$var1 = John.2013-01-01 10:00:00; // I put the dot here so I can explode it later
$var2 = Pete.2013-01-02 10:00:00;
etc
```

Since each customer has a different amount of purchases I need a code that assigns for each purchase (from a given buyer) a different var name and it must be done in a dinamic way.
I thought I would need to do some foreach loop, but the more I look into this problem more I get confused.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(BUYER_NAME,".",PURCHASE_DATE) AS BUYER_NAME.PURCHASE_DATE FROM table WHERE 1
```

Comment: I will test it, but it seems that I still have to assign those ROWS variable names. Since each customer has a different amount of purchases I need a code that assigns for each purchase (from a given buyer) a different var name and it must be done in a dinamic way.